# How to correctly use PLAY_VIDEO in Mirror API

Tags: python, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I've been playing around with the Google Glass Mirror API and want to be able to stream a video.

This is the Python code snippet I tried:

```
def _insert_item_video_stream(self):
    """Insert a timeline item with streaming video."""
    logging.info('Inserting timeline item with streaming video')
    body = {
        'notification': {'level': 'DEFAULT'}, 
        'menuItems' : [{'action' : 'PLAY_VIDEO'},
                       {'payload' : 'https://eye-of-the-hawk.appspot.com/static/videos/waterfall.mp4'}],
    }
    self.mirror_service.timeline().insert(body=body).execute()
    return 'A timeline item with streaming video has been inserted.'
```

However, the video was just blank.  Any ideas would be super helpful!

Comment: Your payload looks fine, but I just pulled up the video (https://eye-of-the-hawk.appspot.com/static/videos/waterfall.mp4) in my web browser and it appears blank. Have you tried this with other videos? What codec is being used? H.264 baseline works best on Glass.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, Jenny! Per your comment, I was able to convert to H.264 (at http://eye-of-the-hawk.appspot.com/static/videos/waterfall2.mp4). Then I had to fix something else for it to "stream" correctly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix this after removing two brackets! Oh, Python. :/

This is the fixed line:

```
   'menuItems' : [{'action' : 'PLAY_VIDEO', 'payload' : 'https://eye-of-the-hawk.appspot.com/static/videos/waterfall.mp4'}],
```